# Microsoft Word 2007 diff

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, diff

Does Word 2007 come with diff functionality?

If not, what's the easiest way of creating a patch file between two documents showing the changes I have made?

Comment: Use whatever tool to do the diff that shows the results and then take screenshots of the side by side result (per page/section of screen where you have to scroll to next section/screen) if there's no export option? One tool to try is WordDocDiff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the Review tab, there's an option to compare documents and merge them into one:

[image]

Comment: I guess I can't make a merge patch together. I'll tell my friend to compare with the original himself.